# Make webserver run Angular 5 application with npm start instead of ng serve

Tags: angular, proxy, webserver

When I run Angular 5 application locally with **npm start** it seems everything is OK, my proxy is fetched and requests are redirected. But when I run application on webserver remotely proxy does not works.
I assume it starts with **ng serve** and proxy is not set while server is starting.
Could you help how to make the webserver running with **npm start**? Or probably how to set proxy during build?

Comment: I think you will need to provide more information, the webserver is apache? or nginx? How it launchs?...

Comment: If you're trying to deploy it, you should do so with the artefacts built using `ng build`, and serving it statically, not using a dev server

Comment: @user184994 Could you provide example how to set proxy via **ng build**?